# Div to have scrollbar html?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a better website for my school. So I have it setout like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHAzx.png)

But the main `div` doesn't show the scroll bar.

I have hidden the scrollbar in the `body` element, and set it as visible in the `main` div element.

However it doesn't show, nor can I scroll down in it.

Any answer to this?

Comment: Did you specify a `height` and `overflow-y: auto` ?

Comment: @JoeDF no, but I have now. Thank you. That has solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I just used `overflow-y: auto` and that worked. Thanks @JoeDF

Comment: Glad I could help!